# Asserting $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} |_x = \frac{T_{1y}}{T_{1x}}$ for wave characteristics on a string

Tags: waves, string, continuum-mechanics

There have been two issues I've been running into trying to understand the derivation of wave speed on a string, as well as wave energy transport on a string, which have boiled down to the same gap in my understanding. I have snapshots of the gap in my knowledge for [the wave speed on a string derivation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqyV8.jpg) and [understanding wave energy transport on a string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCmZb.jpg) in the hyperlinks. They seem to be caused by me failing to understanding this:

$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}|_x = \frac{T_{1y}}{T_{1x}}$$

Where the vertical line and subscript is meant to indicate "evaluated at $x$". I don't see where this comes from given the graphics given, and yet it is key to understanding it, generally, for both concepts I'm highlighting. Can someone justify this equation?

Comment: The derivative is the tangent of the string. It is the same as the ratio of the components of the tension.

Comment: -1 Not clear what you are asking, in view of Pieter's comment and knzhou's answer. It is an elementary property of strings, not waves.

Answer (score 1):

This equation says that the tension in the string is directed parallel to the string. In particular, that means both the string and the tension vector have the same slope, so $\partial y / \partial x = T_y / T_x$.

Comment: That seems to represent the picture. I just find the idea of a string having a slope to be a weird in a maths perspective. Do you think this seems justifiable?

Comment: @sangstar A string is a curve, and a curve has a slope. Does that make sense to you?

Comment: Yes. So you’re saying the $y$ versus $x$ graph is implied here to basically be a snapshot of the string? And thus we are then contending that the rate of curvature of the string, keeping time constant, is the exact same as the ratio between the tensions. Okay. But why do we know it *is* the same?

Comment: @sangstar Yes, $y$ is defined to be the height of the string at horizontal position $x$. I’m not sure what else you’re asking: the slope of a vector is equal to the slope of a parallel vector almost by definition.

Comment: Right, but how do we know the tension vector and string are parallel? The net tension on the string should be vertical.

Comment: @sangstar That’s part of the definition of an ideal string. If you allow for more general forces, you’re dealing with something else, like a metal bar, for which the math gets much more complicated. (Look up ‘beam theory’ for an example. Even figuring out _static_ configurations is hard.) A real string can exert a small non-parallel force but for the sake of simplicity we neglect it.

Comment: @sangstar The net force is the sum of two tension forces, and is vertical. Each individual tension force is parallel to the string at the point it’s applied.

Answer (score 0):

So, it's a bit hard to explain. This is a mixture of:

- a constraint
- an unusual, or hard to represent assumption about the string
- a state-transition, from imparting the oscillation to uninterrupted oscillation, for which the description remains valid

So when imparting vertical momentum to the string, impulse-momentum gives $$F_yt=mv_y$$which implies that during this motion, each segment of string has the same velocity, and only more of the string gets involved.

Each bit has different departure time, but the same velocity -- it's easy to see that the string will have $\partial y / \partial x$ everywhere the same.

What's less clear is that the components of impulse and components of momentum may be superposed, and baked into this is the assumption that perfectly-elastic, horizontal, intra-string collisions conserve momentum, and by impulse-momentum applied to the horizontal portion (which is only moving virtually), triangle similarity, owing to the superposition vacuum we've drawn around the situation gives: $${F_y \over T} = {v_y t \over v_xt}$$
which gives simple algebraic path to $${F_y \over T} ={\partial y / \partial t \over\partial x / \partial t}={\partial y \over \partial x}$$

Comment: And to be completely honest I find [the purely geometric argument](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r2GIY2ZmXPY) to be a little bit more obvious, if you only need *an* explanation, though I value the wisdom you can glean from this derivation as well, the reach of impulse-momentum is probably more arcane than the calculus applied.